# Apache 2 Virtual Hosts Sharing 1 Common Directory

Tags: apache, virtualhost

I have 2 virtual sites that go to the same directory outside of the specified directory.  For example.

```
example1.com -> /var/www/example1
/var/www/example1/index.html meta redirects to /var/www/common/index.php?id=example1

example2.com -> /var/www/example2
/var/www/example2/index.html meta redirects to /var/www/common/index.php?id=example2
```

the problem is that I get a Apache Not Found error.  However, '`locahost/example1`' works fine and '`locahost/example2`' works fine.  The issue is in the virtual host configuration, maybe?

Both are (abbreviated)...

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName example1.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/example1
</VirtalHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName example2.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/example2
</VirtalHost>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth I could not get this figured out.  I did end up doing the two virtual servers in the web root and then from there using server side php to control content.  If anyone thinks this is bad or has an actual answer to this question, I would love to know.